# How to save current sysdate in apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX to build an interactive report, in the edit page, there is a display only field called update time and the value is the last updated time. When I click submit page, I want to update this field to the current sysdate.

What I did is that I created a dynamic action which fires when page uploaded. The action changes the update time field to the current sysdate. However, this doesn't work. I am wondering if there is any other ways to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a unique column in your table, you can create a procedure in page processing section and assign it to the submit page button. When you click submit button, procedure will update the update time field.

To make a page processing:

- Go to Process section and click create button
- Select PL/SQL Code as Process Type
- Give a name to your Process
- Write your procedure in field. You can assign a fields value like: update table set update_time = sysdate where ID = :P3_ID
- You can define success or error message
- Define your button to When Button Pressed section

Hope this helps.

Comment: your method for update time works, but for adding creation time in create page this doesn't work, please refer to this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276122/failed-to-create-creation-time-in-apex-report), thanks a lot! @F. Erdi